# Google App Engine 500 error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

So I've deployed my app to GAE, but all I get is a 500 error on the index page, which is just a plain crossroads site. Since I am not at all an expert on Java, I need some help with decoding the error log.
Do you have any idea what to do in order to make the app work again (it has been working already)?

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1370ce9{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~dobekologistics/3.354826916826026599}
    org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:392)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:79)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:165)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:256)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayProperty.<init>(ArrayProperty.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.<init>(ArrayERProperty.java:84)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:96)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:33)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:515)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:330)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:159)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:311)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:357)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:264)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:66)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:94)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initWadl(WebApplicationImpl.java:1207)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.processRootResources(WebApplicationImpl.java:1106)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:912)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:589)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:403)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:252)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:550)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:201)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:307)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:470)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:79)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:165)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:256)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayProperty.<init>(ArrayProperty.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.<init>(ArrayERProperty.java:84)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:96)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:33)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:515)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:330)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:159)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:311)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:357)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:264)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:66)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:94)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initWadl(WebApplicationImpl.java:1207)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.processRootResources(WebApplicationImpl.java:1106)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:912)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:589)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:403)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:252)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:550)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:201)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:307)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:470)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

    Uncaught exception from servlet
    javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:211)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:392)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error, and it went away when I disabled WADL in my web.xml file (see init-param stanza under the servlet-class tag).  The logs hinted at this, where you see wadl references before the crash.  I made this change and restarted, and it worked.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jerseywebapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked for me. Man I hate not knowing why something works, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found someone that posted a [similar problem](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/dc8ed0738064f486/4be34ebef5a91b08?lnk=raot), because I too am having the same problem.

His solution that I quote:

> I just played around a bit and it seems that the problem is jaxb-impl 
>   (group com.sun.xml.bind). 
>   Version 2.1.12 works (yea!), version 2.2.4 (latest) does not work on 
>   App Engine production

Comment: Big thanks to you after 3 days of work you post fix my problem. I'm currently working with enunciate API. By default Enunciate 1.25 don't use jaxb 2.1.12 so I get the same error... By overwriting my pom.xml   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.12</version>
  </dependency> I get it working !

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar stack trace, but after doing some Investigation I realized the Injector was being included in my project in a jaxb-impl library via a Maven transitive dependency of jersey-json project.  I excluded the jaxb-impl library, rebuilt and redeployed and got past the problem.  JAXB is provided by JDK6 so you were likely having the same problem.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.11</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that Jetty is failing because some of the stuff that your application is using has thrown an exception during static initialization.  This is causing the failure of a subsequent class load of `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector`.

Unfortunately, the root cause of the problem is not shown in these messages.

You need to check the log files for an earlier entry (probably with a stack trace) that reports the static initialization problem that triggered these ones.